# two columns of posts on homepage, one of them "favorites"

Tags: php, css, child-theme, homepage, theme-twenty-twelve

I'm using a child theme of Twenty Twelve in wordpress. Here's where I am developing the site:

http://internalcompass.us/castle/

You'll notice the two columns of posts on the homepage. I have one labeled recent posts and one labeled favorites. In actuality, both columns are the same - recent posts organized by date. I'd like to actually create a set of posts that populate the second column, so my client can select recommended posts or her favorite posts for that column. I'd like the first column to be recent posts.

I'm hearing crickets on the Wordpress Support forum, likely because this is a pretty technical q. sooooo Any info is appreciated. I'm sure I can somehow label posts and add code to the index.html to populate the second column. I just am not yet equipped with the info to know what code to add.

Peace & thx

Comment: if you can't help, can you recommend another site like this where i could ask my q? thx!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are hearing "crickets" because there are several component to this. You need to:

1. Create a meta_box
2. Save data from that meta box
3. And build a Loop on the front

For #1 and #2:

```
function add_featured_meta_box() {
  add_meta_box("featureddiv", "Featured Post", "featured_post_meta_box", 'post', "side", "low");
}
add_action("do_meta_boxes", "add_featured_meta_box");

function featured_post_meta_box(){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $featured = (!empty($custom["_featured"][0])) ? $custom["_featured"][0] : ''; ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Featured
        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="featured" <?php checked($featured,true); ?> /> </td>
    </tr>
</table><?php
}

function save_featured_meta($postid,$post){
  global $_POST;
  // set the ID to the parent post, not the revision
  $postid = (wp_is_post_revision( $postid )) ? wp_is_post_revision( $post ) : $postid;
  $post_type = get_post_type( $postid );
  if (isset($_POST['featured'])) {
    update_post_meta($postid, "_featured", true);
  } else {
    delete_post_meta($postid, "_featured", true);
  }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_featured_meta', 1, 2);
```

And for #3:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => '_featured',
      'value' => true,
    )
  )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Barely tested. Possibly buggy. *Caveat emptor*. No refunds.

Comment: do i put the first one in functions.php and the latter in index.php? i'll try anything at this point.

Comment: Put the first block, ideally, in a plugin file. The second block will pull your posts for the loop on the index page.

Answer (score 0):

A quick method would be to add a category favorite and filter the loop by only pulling posts from that category. The client could then check and un-check the favorite category on posts. Here is a rough of the args array for the loop.

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'favorite',
    'post_type' => 'post', //or whatever post type you need
);

$posts = query_posts( $args );
if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
    <article id="post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="post type-post post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full' ); ?>
            <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        </header>
    </article>   
<?php
   endwhile;
   endif;
   wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: this looks like exactly what i need to do, yes. thank you. i'm still new to this, so: does what you gave me above go in index.html in the child theme? feel free to refer me to another resource, i just haven't ever created a loop.

Comment: yes it goes where you want the favorite loop and inside of the if statement is where you put the html so it would like something like the edit i will make above, its hard to add code to comments.

Comment: here are some decent resources to help you further: [WP_Query](http://http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [wptuts](http://wp.tutsplus.com), the first is the codex for WP_Query but it shows examples of custom loops, and the second is an excellent resource for wordpress information and tutorials. hope this helps you out. If you liked my answer remember to vote it up! =]

Comment: thanks. i know this info is putting me on the right track, so i appreciate it. it isn't working so far, and i'm not sure why although i know it's just my own learning curve. i am reading about the loop on codex to see if i can better understand... one thing is that i didn't know where to put the code in the index.html .. i took a guess which was wrong. the two column feature, i specified in the style.css file, so it's still a mystery to me how the site will know to put the loop i'm adding now in the second column rather than the first. but not getting an error message would be a good start:)

Comment: just saw the resources you posted. thx a lot. & i will vote.

Comment: if i could see the html for the index page it would help but the code snippet i posted goes exactly where you want the html it generates to show up so if you had `<div class="favorite-posts"></div>` you would put the code in that div. it outputs it exactly where it is in the file.

Comment: ok, i'll try to paste the code in case that makes any lightbulbs go off for you.. if not, no sweat. i got an error at the line that had endwhile so i took that part out. and now using your code, i've somehow made the favorites posts start showing up at the bottom of the page (yay!), except they look way too wide and a little psycho and aren't in the columns. clearly, i'm an amateur.

Comment: the code i have in the child theme index.html is:

Comment: oh nevermind. can't paste it. feel free to look at the page in firebug or whatever. it's internalcompass.us/castle

Comment: okay i reviewed your site and although i updated the code above and you could copy and past it in to your template, the loop in the template add a class of two-column-post-left to every other article so would need two custom loops, one for regular posts then one for favorites then you would have to combine in an array so you could output them one and one, that is beyond the scope of this site so i wish you the best of luck, but so you know you can copy my code in to your template and it will generate the posts you need, modifying it to work with your current template structure will take work.